# Flex or flash interface components for developing IOS apps?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, user-interface, ios4

I'm developing apps for the IOS platform using Flash CS5, but the interface components (like listbox, combobox, buttons and so) that comes with flash/flex are not optimized for IOS developing. Is out there a free library of components for the interface on IOS??? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Reflex](http://groups.google.com/group/reflex-steering-committee) and [MinimalComps](http://www.minimalcomps.com/) .

I was also recently provided these links as additional references:

http://custardbelly.com/blog/?p=173

http://blog.kevinhoyt.org/?p=548

Answer (score 2):

Without any doubt, my favorite emerging and performant components skinned for iOS is Eskimo http://e-skimo.com/

Update: If you would like to use Stage3D UI Components (to access Hardware acceleration), you can use Foxhole: http://joshblog.net/2012/04/03/foxhole-mobile-ui-controls-for-starling/